# C# delegate question

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Delegate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044301/what-is-delegate)

In C#, a delegate can be seen as both method name and type name. Is my understanding right?

like "doShow[] items = new doShow[3];"  dowShow is type name.
like "doshow(new Class1()....)"   dosShow is a method name/

I get this conclusion by reading codes here:

```
public class TestDelegate
{
    // define a datatype as a method taking a string returning void
    public delegate void doShow(String s);

    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        // make an array of these methods
        doShow[] items = new doShow[3];

        items[0] = new doShow(new Class1().show);
        items[1] = new doShow(new Class2().display);
        items[2] = new doShow(Class3.staticDisplay);

        // call all items the same way
        for(int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
            items[i]("Hello World");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think of it as a type that describes a method; not an actual method. The delegate says *which* method gets called (or an anonymous method). Loosely put, you could say it's a strongly typed function pointer.

Comment: In simple terms you can assume delegates as containers for method signatures. Its sort of a invisible link to a the method you wish to invoke.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  A delegate type is a type.  An instance of a delegate type can be invoked like a method with (method syntax `myDelegate(arg1, arg2)`).  A delegate can be thought of as a strongly typed (hence the Type) method pointer.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, delegate is always a type, but its instance can be associated to a method with the identical signature. This is what you are seeing in the above code.

doShow is a type and then its instances (using the new operator) are associated with the methods passed as parameters to the constructor of the delegate.

Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't think of delegates themselves as "methods", even though you can **use instances of them** in much the same way. They are not methods, they are types.

They are a special type, instances of which can hold references to methods. The "name" you give to a delegate is not a method name, it's a type name, like any class, enum, etc. That type just happens to describe an object that can be executed by calling it, just like a method.

It's important to make the distinction between a delegate and "a method name" for several reasons:

1. Most importantly -- you don't use the delegate type name itself to call the associated methods. You use the instance name. Given your sample, you cannot say:

   ```
   doShow("Hi");
   ```
2. A delegate can hold a reference to an anonymous method that has no name, such as:

   ```
   doShow s = delegate ( string s ) { Console.WriteLine(s); };
   ```
3. A delegate can hold a reference to a lamba expression, which is **internally** just a different way to write an anonymous delegate method, but **superficially** looks completely different:

   ```
   doShow s = x => Console.WriteLine(x);
   ```
4. Multi-cast delegates (such as event handlers) can hold references to more than one method at a time, including any combination of named methods, anonymous methods, or lambas.

   ```
   myObject.MyEvent += ObjectEvent;
   myObject.MyEvent += delegate ( object sender, EventArgs e ) { Console.WriteLine("Hi"); }
   myObject.MyEvent += ( sender, e ) => Console.WriteLine("Hi again.");
   ```